# How to force Client to use specific/local IPv6 address to access webserver

Tags: networking, apache-2.4, ipv6

I'm running an Apache 2.4.29 web server with virtual hosts, of which some are publicly available, other shall only be accessible via local network. I have IPv6 up and running.

The corresponding setting in vhost config:

```
<Directory /var/www/mylocalapp>
   Require ip 192.168.10.0/24
   Require ip fd4f:2854:491d:9469::/64
   Require host mynetwork.local
</Directory>
```

Here's the problem:

- Some of the clients in the network use IPv4 addresses -> works
- Some of them use their local IPv6 address (prefix or full address assigned via DHCPv6)
- Some use their global IPv6 address -> NOT WORKING

Example:
When I open a webbrowser to access the local web application, I get the typical error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I can't see any way to force clients to use the locally assigned IPv6 addresses on the local network. Would additional routing information be helpful? But where to put? and how?

Example address listing from one of the Win10 machines. Local network is mentioned as preferred ("Bevorzugt"). But this doesn't help.

```
C:\Users\me> ipconfig /all
Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter WLAN:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: heimnetz.loc
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 64-5D-86-9A-6F-05
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a01:5c0:e080:0001::1a9(Bevorzugt)
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 2. Mai 2019 00:20:59
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 2. Mai 2019 01:50:58
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a01:5c0:e080:2090:b4a0:a49:c44e:c698(Bevorzugt)
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a01:5c0:e089:0001::1a9(Bevorzugt)
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Montag, 22. April 2019 03:37:54
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Sonntag, 8. Juni 2155 07:24:25
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : fd4f:2854:491d:9469::1a9(Bevorzugt)
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 2. Mai 2019 00:20:59
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 2. Mai 2019 01:50:58
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : fd4f:2854:491d:9469:b4a0:a49:dead:beef(Bevorzugt)
   Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : 2a01:5c0:e080:0001:a413:ba9d:f05e:154(Bevorzugt)
   Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . : fd4f:2854:491d:9469:a413:ba9d:f05e:154(Bevorzugt)
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::b4a0:a49:0001:c698%12(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.89(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Mittwoch, 1. Mai 2019 22:20:55
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 2. Mai 2019 01:50:56
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::be05:43ff:0001:926f%12
                                       192.168.10.1
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.2
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 174349702
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-23-58-60-FE-9C-EB-E8-57-D7-E7
   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : fd4f:2854:491d:9469:133a:920e:1234:5678
                                       2a01:5c0:e080:0001:65f0:bda5:8765:4321
                                       192.168.10.2
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert
```

Desired behaviour is, that all machines prefer local IPv6 addresses to access resources in the local network. This behaviour shall be automatically assigned (e.g. via DHCP option).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. Your internal DNS servers should serve to internal clients only ULA addresses for resources inside your network, not global addresses. Or...
2. You can allow the global IPv6 address range in the Apache configuration.

Comment: For global addresses only the prefix is delivered to clients. Local addresses are delivered in full for fixed clients, others get the local prefix and calculate their address.

And it's my intention to only accept local connections, so allowing the global prefix would be just that what I don't want. And it wouldn't work, I guess - because the global prefix changes daily.

Comment: @DerPeer First, why are you putting the global addresses in your internal DNS, then? Second, why is your prefix changing daily? It sounds like your ISP is doing something terribly wrong, and you should get that fixed soon.

Comment: hmm... I need to distribute global prefix somehow, don't I? Else clients wouldn't be able to calculate their address to access IPv6 based internet...

And it's common procedure of ISPs, to change IPs every day... at least here in Germany. Like for decades with IPv4 they do it now with IPv6 prefix.

Comment: Oh, you're in Germany? No, they're doing it wrong. It's a very common problem with German ISPs. As for your immediate problem, you didn't answer my question: Why are you putting global addresses in your internal DNS if you didn't intend to use them to access your internal resources?

Comment: Well, I can't change that... it's just as it is.
To your question... I have them, because some specific resouces shall also be accessible from outside. Therefore (and because I don't want to stick to IPv4 eternally) some time ago I set up IPv6 on my network.
And that's really the point: by determining the IPs to use, shouldn't it be possible to have clients connected to a "bigger" network and still keep some communication in a local network without using NAT? Wasn't that a design goal within IPv6

Comment: @DerPeer OK, then the problem really is the fact that your ISP is changing your prefix every day. This is extremely bad practice for providing Internet service to a business, and it's not very good for a home connection either. Now you are experiencing _why_ this is such a problem. Renumbering is _expensive_. If I had to renumber every day, I wouldn't have time to do anything else, and production would never be up. You should spend more time talking to your ISP and trying to convince them to do the right thing and stop changing your prefix.

Comment: That's not the point, @michael-hampton. You're right, that changing prefixes is a pain in the ass, but I can cope with that, using DynDNS services.
As I wrote in my original question, I want to use a local network (fd:: ...) for local communication. And apache shall - for specific services - only listen on the local addresses. How do I get clients to use their local address to connect to that service. Atm some (seemingly randomly) use their global address.

Comment: @DerPeer Go back to point 1 in my original answer.